# Use different database authentication methods for design time and runtime in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

**Runtime:**
I am using .NET 6 and EF Core in an Azure Function. To connect with an Azure SQL Database, I want to use AAD-Authentication, so I configured my DbContext as follows:

```
public class FunctionContext : DbContext {

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new();
            
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userAssignedClientId") });
            var token = credential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
            connection.ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
            connection.AccessToken = token.Token;

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
            optionsBuilder.UseExceptionProcessor();
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        }
}
```

The connection string "SqlConnectionString" is available as an environment variable and has the following form:
`"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Database=testdb";`

**Migrations:**
I want to update the database with every deployment. I am using Azure DevOps pipelines to deploy the application, and I have a service principal that I can use to log in. So I need to use a connection string that looks like this:
`"Server=demo.database.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory Service Principal; Encrypt=True; Database=testdb; User Id=AppId; Password=secret";`

Is there a possiblity to use two different connection strings for runtime and migrations?

I tried modifiying the Factory method that Update-Database uses to create the context, but since the `OnConfiguring` method pasted above is called anyway, I still end up with the same connection string.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#aspnet-core-environment

Comment: Thank you, I think you're hinting at the "--context" option. Can I use a new class, e.g. "DeploymentContext : DbContext" and specify a new OnConfiguring method? Would that not clash with the existing FunctionContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was not to implement the `OnConfiguring` method, but pass the configuration directly in the `Startup.cs` as follows:

**Startup.cs (Context at runtime)**

```
internal class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddDbContext<FunctionContext>(options =>
        {   
            SqlConnection connection = new();

            var credentialOptions = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { 
                ManagedIdentityClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userAssignedClientId")};
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(credentialOptions);
            var token = credential.GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
            connection.ConnectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");
            connection.AccessToken = token.Token;

            options.UseSqlServer(connection);
            options.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
            options.UseExceptionProcessor();
            options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        });
    }
}
```

**DesignTimeFunctionContextFactory.cs (Context at design time)**

```
    public class DesignTimeFunctionContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<FunctionContext>
    {
        public FunctionContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FunctionContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlAdminConnectionString"), options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure());
            return new FunctionContext(optionsBuilder.Options); 
        }
    }
```